# What is a recurve bow?

Tags: gear, archery, recurve-bow

When I hear people talking about archery or I read something about it, there is often a "recurve bow" mentioned. Altough I know how it's shaped etc. I wanted to know what exactly makes a bow to a recurved one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### A bow whose string touches a section of the limb ...

Yeah, all these different bows may confuse a beginner. However, it's generally really easy like in this case. A recurve is simply defined as "a bow of which the string touches a section of the limb when it is strung".

To further explain this definition refer to this image:

[image: Recurve bow]

- The string: as you might have guessed it's the straight, drilled cord
- The limb: the bent wood

As you can see the string "touches" the wooden limb for about 3" on the top. As soon as this happens, the bow is a recurve bow.

### But what about the shape?!

Ah, a nice topic. One might guess that a recurve is shaped in a particular way and that's why it's a recurve. That's (surprisingly) wrong!

*Note: Before you read further. There are a few more details which make a "horseman bow" different from a "recurve" but that's another topic.*

Let's examine a so called "horseman bow":

[image: Horseman bow]

And now a recurve bow:

[image: Recurve bow]

Okay, besides the "waves" in the limbs pretty much the same, eh? But have you mentioned the tips?

Horseman bow string doesn't touch the limb:

[image: No touch]

Whereas a recurve's cuddles:

[image: Recurve bow]

### Conclusion

> A recurve bow has tips that curve away from the archer when the bow is
>   unstrung. By definition, the difference between recurve and other bows
>   is that the string touches a section of the limb when the bow is
>   strung. A recurve bow stores more energy and delivers energy more
>   efficiently than an equivalent straight-limbed bow, giving a greater
>   amount of energy and speed to the arrow. A recurve will permit a
>   shorter bow than the simple straight limb bow for a given arrow energy
>   and this form was often preferred by archers in environments where
>   long weapons could be cumbersome, such as in brush and forest terrain,
>   or while on horseback.

From [Wikipedia - Bow shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bow_shape#Recurve_bows)